# Why is my output throwing an unexpected result?

Tags: python, url

I am unsure why my code is not working. I have it copied verbatim from my instructor.

```
import urllib

def read_text():
    quotes = open("C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\movie_quotes.txt")
    contents_of_file = quotes.read()
    print(contents_of_file)
    quotes.close()
    check_profanity(contents_of_file)


def check_profanity(text_to_check):
    connection = urllib.urlopen("http://www.wdyl.com/profanity?q="+text_to_check)
    output = connection.read()
    print(output)
    connection.close()

read_text()
```

And the output:

```
<html><head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>404 Not Found</title>
    </head>
    <body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
    <h1>Error: Not Found</h1>
    <h2>The requested URL <code>/profanity?q=shot</code> was not found on this server.</h2>
    <h2></h2>
    </body></html>
```

Why is this happening?

Thank you!!

Comment: Please provide sample content of text-file.

Comment: http://www.wdyl.com/ Appears to not be a valid place to go.

Comment: WYDL is not active anymore: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WDYL_(search_engine)

Comment: @albert: Why do you say that? The page you linked says, "Current status: Active".

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a problem with your code. It's just that the site it's attempting to access is not functional.

Comment: Wikipedia says "was a metasearch engine from Google" despite of "Current status: Active". However, the site does not seem to be available but is advertised at https://www.thinkwithgoogle.com/campaigns/google-what-do-you-love.html. So the problem of the error raised by the code might be at Google.

Answer (score 0):

www.wdyl.com doesn't work anymore.

You can use What do you like instead: http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q=foo